# Reactive Command with parameters. Is it OK?

Tags: .net, reactive-programming, reactiveui

I'm making a simple calculator using ReactiveUI.

In the GUI, each digit of the calculator is bound to the same ReactiveCommand called `EnterDigit`

`ReactiveCommand.Create(param => AddDigit(param));`

Otherwise, I would have to define a command for each digit, what is plain nonsense.

While this can be OK for other MVVM frameworks, I wonder if  **is it a recommended practice when using ReactiveUI**. I remember I have seen somewhere that passing parameters to the commands is not recommended, anyways.

Is it a recommended practice in this case? If it's not, how to deal with this scenario?

Comment: Part of your job as a software developer is to decide whether it's OK or not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Another part of my job as a software developer is to gather experience from experts in the topic to avoid reinventing the wheel and to do things right. It's a balance after all. That's why I'm asking.

Comment: What do you suppose is the most likely scenario?  That someone is going to tell you you need a dozen methods, one for each digit; that you need a global variable so that you don't have to pass a parameter to a command; or that you should probably just pass a parameter to the command?  Common-sense would seem to rule the day here.

Comment: Also, you haven't stated any criteria for evaluating "recommended."  Would it be a better design from your perspective if you used a global variable instead, or used one command per key?  Read [Why Questions about the Correct Way are Too Broad](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8965/why-questions-about-the-correct-way-are-too-broad).  There isn't *any* software design that is "recommended" in all scenarios.

Comment: @RobertHarvey ReactiveUI has a lot of differing recommended practices especially around Commands and bindings so the question is less "open" than it sounds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ReactiveCommand` supports parameters to commands just fine. You can just not use it for the `canExecute` condition like you would with other frameworks, in those scenarios it's better to have a bound ViewModel property.

In fact there are overloads to the `BindCommand` in code behind bindings that support passing of parameters.